# Awkward Crash in the Application - Crash Log Attached

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, logging

I get the following Crash Log - Please do let me know what might be the reason for this.

Thanks

```
Incident Identifier: 33B96EF5-4158-4C0B-9BC1-AF1D2D176A85
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         Vivian Aranha [1838]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CFF7068A-A0AB-4555-860E-84518E666A0D/VivianAranha.app/VivianAranha
Identifier:      VivianAranha
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-12-03 08:09:24.884 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  6

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561010 mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561206 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33f7841c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33f7711a __CFRunLoopRun + 818
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa39e CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   GraphicsServices                0x35b3afc6 GSEventRunModal
7   UIKit                           0x3503f73c UIApplicationMain
8   VivianAranha                    0x0000242c main (main.m:14)
9   VivianAranha                    0x000023e4 0x000023e4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x365613b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37287e78 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37287b96 _dispatch_mgr_thread

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   ImageIO                         0x36694940 XMPMeta::RegisterNamespace(char const*, char const*, char const**, unsigned int*) + 36
1   ImageIO                         0x366943cc XMPMeta::Initialize() + 1324
2   ImageIO                         0x36693dbc WXMPMeta_Initialize_1 + 80
3   ImageIO                         0x36693d32 TXMPMeta<std::string>::Initialize() + 10
4   ImageIO                         0x3673073e CreateMetadataFromXMPDataInternal(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned int) + 174
5   ImageIO                         0x3673ed04 readXMPProperties + 20
6   ImageIO                         0x3667e188 initImagePng + 2172
7   ImageIO                         0x3667d904 _CGImagePluginInitPNG + 4
8   ImageIO                         0x3667d45e makeImagePlus + 622
9   ImageIO                         0x36682688 _CGImageSourceGetPropertiesAtIndexInternal + 32
10  ImageIO                         0x36682638 CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex + 104
11  WebCore                         0x34408d2c WebCore::ImageSource::isSizeAvailable()
12  WebCore                         0x34408b72 WebCore::BitmapImage::dataChanged(bool)
13  WebCore                         0x34408a8a WebCore::Image::setData(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer>, bool)
14  WebCore                         0x3440879c WebCore::CachedImage::data(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer>, bool)
15  WebCore                         0x34407eda WebCore::CachedResourceRequest::didReceiveData(WebCore::SubresourceLoader*, char const*, int)
16  WebCore                         0x34407a9c WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveDataArray(__CFArray const*)
17  WebCore                         0x34407a14 WebCore::ResourceLoader::didReceiveDataArray(WebCore::ResourceHandle*, __CFArray const*)
18  WebCore                         0x343e2752 WebCore::ResourceHandle::handleDataArray(__CFArray const*)
19  WebCore                         0x343e2722 WebCore::didReceiveDataArray(_CFURLConnection*, __CFArray const*, void const*)
20  CFNetwork                       0x3331905c URLConnectionClient::_clientDidReceiveData(__CFArray const*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*)
21  CFNetwork                       0x3327f550 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long)
22  CFNetwork                       0x3327f632 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long)
23  CFNetwork                       0x3327f23c URLConnectionClient::processEvents()
24  CFNetwork                       0x3327f172 MultiplexerSource::perform()
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33f78afc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
26  CoreFoundation                  0x33f782c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
27  CoreFoundation                  0x33f7706e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
28  CoreFoundation                  0x33efa4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
29  CoreFoundation                  0x33efa39e CFRunLoopRunInMode
30  WebCore                         0x343b6128 RunWebThread(void*)
31  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfc16 _pthread_start
32  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfad0 thread_start

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561010 mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561206 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33f7841c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33f77154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa39e CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   Foundation                      0x319debc2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:]
7   Foundation                      0x319dea8a -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x31a7259a __NSThread__main__
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfc16 _pthread_start
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfad0 thread_start

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36571570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33f7c66a __CFSocketManager
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfc16 _pthread_start
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfad0 thread_start

Thread 5 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561010 mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36561206 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33f7841c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33f77154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33efa39e CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   WebCore                         0x343df69e WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*)
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfc16 _pthread_start
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfad0 thread_start

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3657132c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34e1df54 pthread_kill
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34e16fe4 abort
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dd194a free
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x338b393a operator delete(void*) + 6
5   CFNetwork                       0x332deb28 ProcessCacheTasks(__CFURLCache*, bool)
6   CFNetwork                       0x332dec5a _CFURLCacheTimerCallback(void*)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3728921e _dispatch_source_invoke
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x37286b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x37286caa _dispatch_queue_drain
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x37286b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3728776c _dispatch_worker_thread2
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda1c8 _pthread_wqthread
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda09c start_wqthread

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36571068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddff2e _pthread_cond_wait
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ddfcaa pthread_cond_wait
3   Foundation                      0x319decca -[NSCondition wait]
4   Foundation                      0x319d240c -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:]
5   Foundation                      0x319d1e42 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
6   VivianAranha                    0x0003c2bc -[DDInvocationGrabber forwardInvocation:] (DDInvocationGrabber.m:153)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33fa6aac ___forwarding___
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33f01678 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
9   VivianAranha                    0x0000f842 -[DataService onSectionLoad:] (DataService.m:314)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33f03224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
11  VivianAranha                    0x00053bf0 -[AbstractLoader delegate:config:fromCache:notModified:] (AbstractLoader.m:93)
12  VivianAranha                    0x00054222 -[AbstractLoader loadFromServer:] (AbstractLoader.m:165)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33fa780c __invoking___
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33f027da -[NSInvocation invoke]
15  Foundation                      0x31a60698 -[NSInvocationOperation main]
16  Foundation                      0x319f939c -[__NSOperationInternal start]
17  Foundation                      0x31a6279c __block_global_6
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x3727bd4e _dispatch_call_block_and_release
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x3728779c _dispatch_worker_thread2
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda1c8 _pthread_wqthread
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda09c start_wqthread

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36571cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda30a _pthread_wqthread
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda09c start_wqthread

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36571cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda30a _pthread_wqthread
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34dda09c start_wqthread
```

Comment: Can you add some more details- like what you are trying to do, where at code level this happens. also attach some code as well.

Comment: This is one of the Crash Log I got from the device - I dont know when it was generated - but my app generated a few of these - I dont know what beahviour caused this.

Comment: you can check following thread and try to symbolize your crash log, might be then you will be able to get some more details of this.

Comment: If you see closely you will notice its already symbolized - But still any help is appreciated

Comment: Dig around the line numbers mentioned in your own classes in Thread 7. Are you doing anything with GCD? What kind of network operations are happening in the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Thread 6 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814917/thread-6-com-apple-nsurlconnectionloader-program-received-signal-exc-bad-acce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814917/thread-6-com-apple-nsurlconnectionloader-program-received-signal-exc-bad-acce) fixed my issue