# Crittercism SDK 4.3.7 is crashing in iOS 8.0 device

Tags: ios, crittercism

Crittercism SDK 4.3.7 is crashing in iOS 8.0 :
Getting error at com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader after running application.

Can anybody have solution for this or need to wait for new version of SDK with fix for this bug.

Comment: You should contact the developer of this SDK. Only they can help you.

Comment: Please contact support [at] crittercism.com and the team will help investigate the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try doing this and see where it takes us.

Set NSZombieEnabled, MallocStackLogging, and guard malloc in the debugger. Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
Replace 0x543216 with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

More can be read here: ["Thread 6 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814917/thread-6-com-apple-nsurlconnectionloader-program-received-signal-exc-bad-acce)

FYI we'll be working on tying up any iOS8 related loose ends on the 17th. 
Thanks for using Crittercism!